# jQuery hide and show text already apart of a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've spent the better part of the day trying to figure this problem out and now I'm going to need to ask for help.

I have a modified bootstrap carousel that when clicking through thumbnail nav displays the larger images of the thumbs. The thumb nav-

```
<ul class="carousel-linked-nav" id="front_mktng_list_thumb">
          <li class="active front_mktng_thumbs"><a href="#1"><img class="htttp://link/to.jpg"></a></li>
          <li class="front_mktng_thumbs"><a href="#2"><img class="thumb_mktng_border" src="http://link/to/thumb.jpg"></a></li>
          <li class="front_mktng_thumbs"><a href="#3"><img class="thumb_mktng_border" src="http://link/to/thumb.jpg"></a></li>
          <li class="front_mktng_thumbs"><a href="#4"><img class="thumb_mktng_border" src="http://link/to/thumb.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

The larger images that display in the carousel are based on what the user click in the nav-

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
  <div class="carousel-inner span6 image_mktng_border" id="front_mktng_image" > 
    <div class="active item"><img src="http://link/to/large.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://link/to/large.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://link/to/large.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><iframe width="630" height="330" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xW7AAKjDclQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

There are some hacks in here I need to refactor (interval is a high number to ensure image switching based on user clicks, .stopPropagation not used for href, etc.)

```
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 444000,
    pause: true
  });

  $('.carousel-linked-nav > li > a').click(function() {
      var item = Number($(this).attr('href').substring(1));
      $('#myCarousel').carousel(item - 1);
      $('.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      return false;
  });
```

Now what I have been spending the better part of my day on is getting a descriptive text to display with each image as it shows up. To basically display in the same way the images do but not in the carousel and using the same thumbnail `<a>` to hide and show the text. See image(s).

I'm pretty familiar with how to show hide text with click events but I am unsure as to how to get it working correctly with the existing carousel.

The thought process I have been working through is that I can add a class and `display: none;` to divs containing the descriptive text I want to display. Then I can simply toggle that class (with a conditional) whenever a class I would add when the `a` is clicked.

Do I need to refactor my carousel to allow this behavior (multiple div manipulation)?
Is my thought process/solution incorrect?

I need some advice. Thanks for your attention and for taking a look!

---

### Update

The text I would like to display that is not reflected in the screen shots

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="offset2">
    <div id="first_description">Quick list everything town</div><br>
    <div id="second_description">View of what's been done, what's next and who we're waiting on.</div><br>
    <div id="third_description">Have people do thing for you without looking like a jerk</div><br>
    <div id="fourth_description">Here's how I muthloving use it</div><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are many carousels out there. Which one are you using?

Comment: twitter bootstrap carousel

Comment: where the text you want to display ?

Comment: Twitter bootstrap carousel fires two events, `slide` and `slid`. The functionality you seek will be achieved by writing a handler for one or other of these events. You will need to find a tutorial, or read the API documentation to discover exactly how to do this.

Comment: hm, so text in complete separate element ? how you would to link them ? can you make jsfiddle ? use http://placehold.it/ to setup images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tmacram, I'm not surprised you found this problem difficult due to completely inadequate twitter bootstrap documentation.

The event object passed to `slide` and `slid` handlers allows the active item to be determined with the expression :

```
$(event.target).find('.carousel-inner .active')
```

and hence its index amongst its fellow items :

```
$(event.target).find('.carousel-inner .active').index()
```

Thus, you can select and display the corresponding piece of text :

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function(event) {
    var idx = $(event.target).find('.carousel-inner .active').index();
    msg($(".row .offset2 div").eq(idx).text());
}).trigger('slid');
```

where `msg()` is a function for displaying the text in the appropriate container. You will need to write a function of your own (if not already written).

`.trigger('slid')` is necessary to display the text for the initial carousel item, prior to the first slide action.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ymwL5/1/)** (based on a fork of a demo I found following a search).

Alternatively, you may want to show/hide the text divs directly rather than repeatedly copy the active text - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ymwL5/2/)**

Comment: excellent, thank you this is the functionality I was seeking to implement.